# SQL, PHP - How to select Heading and all Subheadings of current Heading?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I need a select query for search in my e-shop. I have the following mysql table

```
id  |  product_id  |   param   |  value
 1  |      123     |   Head 1  |   v1
 2  |      456     |   Head 1  |   v2
 3  |      789     |   Head 1  |   v3
 4  |      abc     |   Head 2  |   v4
 5  |      def     |   Head 2  |   v5
```

I need to select distinct "param" and  the values corresponding to the param.

Example:

```
Head 1 - v1, v2, v3
Head 2 - v4, v5
```

I need add it to **HTML**:

```html
<h3>Head 1</h3>
<div class="vyber">
 <select>
  <option>v1</option>
  <option>v2</option>
  <option>v3</option>
 </select>
</div>

<h3>Head 2</h3>
<div class="vyber">
 <select>
  <option>v4</option>
  <option>v5</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

My **SQL**:

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM Parametre p
JOIN produkty pr ON p.ProduktID = pr.ProId      
WHERE pr.KATEGORIA_URL = '$Kategoria'
GROUP BY p.Hodnota
ORDER BY p.Param, p.Hodnota
```

And this is **PHP** code

```php
$pamet = '';
$konec = '';
while($ParamVyhladavanieResult = mysqli_fetch_object($ParamVyhladavanie)){

  $Param = htmlspecialchars($ParamVyhladavanieResult->param);
  $Hodnota = htmlspecialchars($ParamVyhladavanieResult->value);
  $CisloHodnoty = $ParamVyhladavanieResult->id;

  if (($ParamVyhladavanieResult->param)!=$pamet)
  {
      $pamet = $ParamVyhladavanieResult->param;

      echo "
      <h3>".$Param."</h3>
      <div class=\"vyber\">
      <select class=\"bielePozadie\" style=\"height:35px;color:#000;border:1px solid grey;outline:none;width:100%\">
      <option value=\"0\">--nevybraté--</option>
      ";
      $konec = "</select>
      </div>";
  }

  echo "   <option value=\"$CisloHodnoty\">".$Hodnota."</option>
  ";
}
echo $konec;
```

Comment: Use simple SELECT query and handle that grouping during looping.

Comment: How? First select all Params, then in while select all values?

Comment: Check the answer i have posted below it is completely according to your need with html and php code. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```sql
SELECT param, GROUP_CONCAT(value) value
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY param
```

Output:

```
|  PARAM |    VALUE |
|--------|----------|
| Head 1 | v1,v2,v3 |
| Head 2 |    v4,v5 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb337/1)** demo

Then you can easily `explode()` values of `value` column while iterating over the resultset and build your html.

Comment: How I can group by Param AND Value?

Answer (score 0):

You can eg. make 2 nested loops:

1. Select dinstict values of param
2. Select values which have param = result from first loop

Another option is to select all - ordered by param - and ask for the difference of param in PHP for creating the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
//First select DISTINCT params
$result = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT param FROM YOUR_TABLE');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // now fetch its values
    $sub_result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE param = "'.$row['param'].'"');
    while($sub_row = mysql_fetch_array($sub_result))
    {
         // generate your HTML here
    }
}
```

Alternate approach

```
$last_param = '';
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE ORDER BY param');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row['param'] != $last_param)
    {
       if($last_param != '')
       {
         ?>
            </select>
     </div>
         <?php 
       }
       $last_param = $row['param'];
       ?>
        <h3><?php echo $last_param; ?></h3>
        <div class="vyber">
          <select>
       <?php
    }
    else
    {
       ?>
       <option><?php echo $row['value'];?></option>
       <?php 
    }
}
```

Comment: this is slowly, with indexes

Comment: How slowly? Your table has integer primary key i.e. id.

Comment: I have not tested alternate solution, but you can use this approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Query in SQL as

```
select param, value from table;
```

In HTML, According to your requirment, we can pass result with json to Javascript and handle from there. Using Jquery for code shor

```
<div id="SelectHolder">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ResultArray = <?php echo json_encode(mysqlresult, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); ?>;
for(var i=0; i<ResultArray.length;i++)
{
   if(document.getElementbyId(ResultArray[i][0])!=undefined && document.getElementbyId(ResultArray[i][0])!=null)
   {
      $('#'+ResultArray[i][0]).append('<option>'+ResultArray[i][1]+'</option>');
   }
   else
   {
     $('#SelectHolder').append('<select id="'+ResultArray[i][0]+'">'+ResultArray[i][0]+'</select>');
     $('#'+ResultArray[i][0]).append('<option>'+ResultArray[i][1]+'</option>');
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `if(Mysqlresult[$i][0]=="Head1")` is dynamic, (more than 5 000 heads), I cant add 5000+ if(), i dont understand this

Comment: I have good this code `$ParamVyhladavanieResult = mysqli_fetch_object($query);` and `var ResultArray = <?php echo json_encode($ParamVyhladavanieResult); ?>`? but, showing nothing :-(

Comment: use mysqli_fetch_array($query); to fetch as array

Comment: array too not showing, screenshot: `http://www.myscreen.cz/img/0852fbc7d57f741281f279fef69cc85b0ffbdb9e` why?

Comment: ok just for checking purpose try to print_r($ParamVyhladavanieResult) and see if it prints you query result. till that i make a code for you

Comment: print_r shows only first row `Array ( [0] => 96781 [id] => 96781 [1] => SD/µSD/MMC slot [Param] => SD/µSD/MMC slot [2] => microSD [Hodnota] => microSD )` , sorry but you edited code still not showing any data

Comment: well i ran this code with my query it prints greatly. Check my code once again i made few changes. and must check you query first seperately running phpmyadmin or other and check what result it gives back.

Comment: Screenshot of the generated `<select>`? I have the same code, nothing shows.